Equivariant disk theorem in dimension 2
All groups I'll consider are finite.
An important part of equivariant differential topology in dimension 3 is the equivariant disk theorem, which says that for a $G$-action on a compact $3$-manifold with boundary $M$, if there is a disjoint, $G$-invariant set of curves on $\partial M$, on which $G$ restricts to preserve orientation, which are null-homotpic in $M$, then there exists a disjoint, $G$-invariant collection of neatly embedded disks in $M$ bounded by our curves.
This theorem (as far as I know) was first proved via minimal surfaces, then reproven without a metric using PL techniques that replicated the minimal surface techniques.
In order to understand this theorem, I want to understand it one dimension down:

Conjecture: Given a $G$-action on a connected, compact surface with boundary, $\Sigma$, and a $G$-invariant, disjoint collection of pairs of points $(a,b)$ on $\partial \Sigma$ (i.e. $S^0$s), if $G$ acts on each pair without swapping $a$ and $b$, then there exists a disjoint, $G$-invariant collection of paths bounded by our chosen pairs. (That is, there is a path from $a$ to $b$ for all chosen pairs $(a,b)$.)

I would love any ideas or references to work that might help or apply here. I am stumped.
One motivation for proving this is as follows: the equivariant disk theorem roughly says that if a curve in a $3$-manifold is invariant and unknotted, then it is equivariantly unknotted in the sense that we have an equivariant collection of Seifert disks. I'd like to extend this to boundary-parallel (trivial) tangles: if a tangle in $M$ is invariant and trivial, then it should be equivariantly trivial. To apply the disk theorem directly we'd need a curve that "closes up" each arc of the tangle along the boundary $\partial M$.
Thanks in advance!

You need more conditions on the pairs of points, namely that they can be connected by pairwise disjoint arcs. How much hyperbolic geometry do you know?

That checks out, and aligns better with the disk theorem anyway. Suppose I do have some system of pairwise disjoint arcs connecting my pairs of points. Then does the conjecture work? If so, why? (Also, I am new here; if this is an appropriate point to edit my question, please let me know.)

I am in a hyperbolic geometry class right now, in fact. That was my first thought, to produce geodesics connecting my points. They'll be disjoint from their orbit if $G$ acts by isometries, but that leaves me with two problems: 1. How do I get $G$ acting my isometries? 2. How do I know my geodesics will be unique, i.e. how do I know there isn't some other path from $a$ to $b$? That feels like hyperbolic geometry.

You also should make some assumptions on $G$, like properness of the action. This will allow you to find a $G$-invariant hyperbolic metric. The conjecture you are making is then true

Okay, thank you. I'm seeing lots of work about this from the hyperbolic side. Thank you for your help! I really appreciate your time and effort. Have a lovely day.

You don’t have to think about it as a hyperbolic thing, as long as you’re comfortable with orbifolds. As long as $G$ acts properly, then the quotient $O=G\backslash\Sigma$ is a 2-dimensional orbifold, and the images of your pairs are pairs of points on $O$. If the pairs on $O$ can be joined by disjoint paths that miss the singular locus, then these paths will lift to an equivariant collection of disjoint paths joining your pairs in $\Sigma$.

@HJRW: You don't even need orbifolds.  Just puncture the surface at the fixed points of the action and you'll get a free action, so the quotient space is a surface.

@AndyPutman: Indeed, that works too! (This is actually more or less how I think about orbifolds.)
